# Run tests for spring gateway

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Gateway application that depends on Eureka and Config Server. When I try to run the tests for this application, they fail because they require Eureka Server and Config Server to be enabled. Is it possible to run tests without first starting these services?

```java
@SpringBootTest
class GatewayApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Maybe there are some solutions for this based on mocks?